# htaccess change url in browser address bar without effecting the website

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I need to change the URL in my browser address box without effecting the website. I don't want to restructure the entire website. Can this be done using htacces?

For example

My current url:

`www.example.com/abc-zyx.php`

I want my URL to look like:

`www.example.com/abc/zyx/`

I have tired using this code:

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+abc-zyx\.php([^\s?/]+) [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ /abc/zyx [R=302,L]`

Thank you.

Comment: super, tried anything?

Comment: yes it is possible. search for: mod rewrite

Comment: I have tried the following:

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+abc-zyx\.php([^\s?/]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /abc/zyx [R=302,L]`